# Alguém tem um exemplo de código utilizando o Marionette em Java para automação de testes?

Tags: testes, automatização, selenium-webdriver

Estou precisando de um exemplo de código utilizando o marionette com Java para automação de testes, li  algumas coisas, mas ainda não  consegui entender  como funciona.

Comment: Não entendi a que Marionette se refere, seria o https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/MarionetteDriver.html (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não tenho conhecimento algum sobre o Marionette, todavia ele esta em desuso conforme o link https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/MarionetteDriver.html

O proprio link cita que é preferivel usar FirefoxDriver com `marionette = true` (ou `false`)

Os seguintes comandos são (leia a propriedade com `System.getProperty()` e defina usando `System.setProperty()` no código Java ou por linha de comando usando a flag `-DpropertyName=value`) usados pelo FirefoxDriver:

| Propriedade | O que faz |
| --- | --- |
| `webdriver.firefox.bin` | A localização do binário/programa usado pra controlar o Firefox |
| `webdriver.firefox.marionette` | Valor deve ser Boolean, se true o standalone-server irá ignorar qualquer requisição a uma habilidade do "marionette" desejadae irá forçar o firefox a usar o GeckoDriver, se false usará Legacy Firefox Driver |
| `webdriver.firefox.profile` | O nome do "perfil" usado quando o firefox inicia. Por padrão ele cria um "perfil" anonimo |
| `webdriver.log.file` | Log de arquivo que recebe o log do javascript (console) |
| `webdriver.firefox.logfile` | Log de arquivo que recebe o stdout/stderr do Firefox |

No wiki ele citam um exemplo com Firebug: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Primeiro baixe o xpi do firebug usando um navegador baseado em Mozilla (como o Firefox) e iniciei ele

```
File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);

//previne exibir a tela de inicio
firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

### DesiredCapabilities

No link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver cita um exemplo com `DesiredCapabilities`:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Obrigada Guilherme :D